# Properties of berries that are not shared by strawberries

Tags: botany

What are examples of properties that (all) berries (from a botanical point of view) have and that strawberries do not have? This does not need to be the exact reason, *why* strawberries are not counted as berries. I'm more looking for properties that emphasize the difference.

Since I'm not a biologist, I'd be happy about simple examples. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you check out [wikipedia on berry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_(botany))?

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Botanically a [berry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_(botany)) is something quite different from what is commonly termed a berry in English.

From that Wikipedia page:

> a berry is a fleshy fruit without a stone produced from a single flower containing one ovary

...

> Berries so defined include grapes, currants, and tomatoes, as well as cucumbers, eggplants (aubergines) and bananas

On the other hand, many things called "berries" (including strawberries) are actually [aggregate fruits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_fruit), which are

> a fruit that develops from the merger of several ovaries that were separate in a single flower

Therefore, the botanical difference is the originating tissue of the fruit: a single flower/one ovary, versus a collection of ovaries grouped together.

These botanical groupings don't have much relevance to practical use (i.e., cooking/nutrition) and there aren't other properties that are definitive for what a berry is and is not. For that reason, there is nothing wrong with referring to strawberries, raspberries, etc, as "berries" in cooking: berry simply has different meaning in botany and culinary fields, just like the many culinary "vegetables" that are botanically "fruits."